# Pass file as a parameter to backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Im trying to pass a file to node from angular.

I have managed to get the frontend up and running. It allows the user to pick a file which she then has acess to in the controller:

```
 scope.upload = function() {

  if (scope.file) {
    var uniqueFileName = 'Test/' + scope.file.name;
    var params = {
      Key: uniqueFileName,
      ContentType: scope.file.type,
      Body: scope.file
    };
    console.log(params);  // Params contains the file I wish to pass to node
  }

}
```

Now how can I pass this parameter to node?

Lets say that I on the server creates a route like this:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

 // Can I get req to hold the param maybe?

});
```

Is it possible for me that pass the parameter directly from the ng-controller to this route somehow?

Thank you

EDIT:

This is what I got so far:

```
scope.upload = function() {

  if (scope.file) {
    var uniqueFileName = 'Test/' + scope.file.name;
    var params = {
      Key: uniqueFileName,
      ContentType: scope.file.type,
      Body: scope.file
    };
    console.log(params);  // Params contains the file I wish to pass to node
    $http
       .post('/uploads', {stickie: params})
       .success(function(data){
           //what to do here
       })
       .error(function(data){
           console.log('Error: ' + data);
       });
  }
```

I should add that the file im trying pass to node is a pdf.

Now I can access the the params-object innode like this:

```
 app.post('/uploads', function(req, res) {

    var file = req.body.stickie;
    console.log(file);
```

But for some reason `stickie.Body` does not seem to get passed along...
Here is what gets logged on the server:

```
{ Key: 'Test/myfilename',
  ContentType: 'application/pdf',
  Body: {} 
}
```

Feels like im close but why doesn´t Body show up?

Answer (score 0):

```
//node.js
app.post('/upload_file', function(req, res){
    var file = req.file;
    res.end();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input').change(function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files;

      $.each(files, function(index, file) {
     var name = file.name;
     var ext = file_extension(name).toLowerCase();
     var size = file.size;
     var type = file.type;

      var fr = new FileReader(); 
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
         fr.onload = function(){
      var new_file = {};
      new_file.name = name;
      new_file.size = size;
      new_file.type = type;
      new_file.content =fr.result; 
           
            send_file(new_file);
       }
      });
    });
})
function send_file(file){
  var url_server = "your_url/upload_file";
  $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : url_server,
  dataType : "json",
  async : true,
  data : ({
   file : file
  }),
  success : function (data) {

  },
  error : function (request, status, error) {
   console.log(request);
  }
 });  
  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I fail to see how this passes my file to node..

Answer (score 0):

use multer for file upload on node server

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer